# Get datetime difference with doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-query

Hi I'm trying to give amount of days and get records between that day and now.

```
            $now = new \DateTime();
            $days = 14;
            $to = $now->sub(new \DateInterval('P'.$days.'D'));
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            $qb->andWhere('c.createdDate BETWEEN :from AND :to')
                    ->setParameter('from', $now)
                    ->setParameter('to', $to);
            $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

in my db **created_date** column and have a record which contain 2018-12-12. But unfortunately query returns no value :(. It would be great help if someone can solve. And I'm using sub to get minus date.

Comment: The `created_date` field is of type `datetime` or `date` in the database? Try `$to = (new \DateTime(sprintf('+%d days', $days)))->setTime(23, 59, 59);`

Comment: date field and I tried datetime too

Comment: There's a difference between both you know. You should know what you are doing, not blindly changing types hoping it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid query is:

```
$from = new \DateTime('-14 days');
$to = (new \DateTime())->setTime(23, 59, 59);

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
$qb->andWhere('c.createdDate BETWEEN :from AND :to')
    ->setParameter('from', $from)
    ->setParameter('to', $to);

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The reason it didn't work for you, is because the `\DateTime` is a mutable type. By changing a copy, you also changed the previous date object:

```
$from = new \DateTime();

// below you mutate the $from object, then return its instance
$to = $from->sub(new \DateInterval('P10D'));
// effect is both $from and $to reference the same object in memory

var_dump(spl_object_hash($from) === spl_object_hash($to));
echo $from->format('Y-m-d') , '<br>';
echo $to->format('Y-m-d');
```

Will result in:

```
bool(true) 
2018-12-07
2018-12-07
```

You mapped the property `createdDate` as `datetime` in Doctrine. Personally I always use the `datetime_immutable` type. Instead of DateTime I get to work with [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php), which, compared to DateTime is immutable by design so I don't have to worry about any references:

```
$from = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$to = $from->sub(new \DateInterval('P10D'));

var_dump(spl_object_hash($from) === spl_object_hash($to));
echo $from->format('Y-m-d') , '<br>';
echo $to->format('Y-m-d');
```

Results in:

```
bool(false)
2018-12-17
2018-12-07
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro for your great explanation and nice answer